# Flutter stream from a dynamic list

Tags: flutter

So I'm trying to get a JSON from an api endpoint and subscribe to it. The endpoint is built on Firebase Cloud Functions.

If doing that, will it update the items when something changes in the database? Or do I have to refresh or move to another view and then back in order to get the changes?

Error: `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

Code and the tutorial which I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvvYA1N-tEc&list=PLLLVjvC0H5GbU-E9hyj9ZEMTtfqmgVwWD

```
 List<Termmodel> list = [];
  StreamController<Termmodel> streamController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamController = StreamController.broadcast();

    streamController.stream.listen((t) => {
          setState(() => list.add(t)),
        });
    _load(streamController);
  }

class Termmodel {
  final String term;
  final String docid;

  Termmodel({this.term, this.docid});

  factory Termmodel.fromJson(Map json) {
    return Termmodel(
      term: json['term'],
      docid: json['docid'],
    );
  }
}
```

Load module:

```
  _load(StreamController<Termmodel> sc) async {
    String url =
        '... api url here ...';

    var client = new http.Client();
    var req = new http.Request('get', Uri.parse(url));
    var streamedRes = await client.send(req);

    streamedRes.stream
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(json.decoder)
        .expand((e) => e)
        .map((data) => Termmodel.fromJson(data))
        .pipe(streamController);
  }
```

The response from API is in this format:

`{"results":[{"docid":"-12345","term":"myterm"}]}`

Comment: Can you please post the widget that you are using to display the results. The output you are returning is a map and not a list

Answer (score 0):

> If doing that, will it update the items when something changes in the database?

Since the endpoint is a Cloud Function, the items won't get updated. You must listen to your database directly to do so.

> Error: `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

You are getting this error because you must pass the items of result `List`, but instead you are passing the `Map` that wraps the result `List`. Try, instead:

```dart
streamedRes.stream
    ...
    .expand((e) => e['results'])
    .map((data) => Termmodel.fromJson(data))
    .pipe(streamController);
```

Comment: Thank you. I already tried that but I get `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.dart(undefined_operator)` I added a bit more code. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Makes sense. `.transform(json.decoder)` is supposed to return `Object`, not `dynamic` as I initally thought. Do you have any idea on which line causes the error.

Comment: It won't let me qdd `.expand((e) => e['results'])` The "error" is a warning in Visual studio code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the initial error: `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`